# Merge same files in folders using bash scripts

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have 2 servers server1 and server2 
I have same folder in both server1 and server2 
/var/logs/linux/  this folder is exists in both server and it contains folders depending on ip of connected devices  for example

> 172.10.5.10  10.10.0.113

and inside these folders there are files which is named depending on date for example

> detail-20191005 detail-20191006

in other words this is the path in  server1  and server2
/var/logs/linux/172.10.0.10/detail-20191005
/var/logs/linux/10.10.0.113/detail-20191006

what I want    to do is merge these files which has same name in same directory 
merge

> 172.10.0.10/detail-20191005 from server1

with

> 172.10.0.10/detail-20191005 in server2

using bash script

Comment: Fine. This describes your job. We do not care about. What is your question?

Comment: if the path names are identical then you don't need a script. look at unix & linux stack exchange how to use [rsync](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/rsync/info)